# problem with standardScaler

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-scaling

problem with standardScaler
hi
I'd like to scale one column in the titanic data set. I am using the following code segment.
for some reason df_scaled results an empty set.
how can I solve it? what is the problem?
ps: new is not empty. I controlled it and fit_transform need 2-D array

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

std_scaler = StandardScaler()
new=train_data['Fare']

df_scaled = std_scaler.fit_transform(new.values.reshape(1,-1))
df_scaled
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose when you said df_scaled is empty, you actually meant all values inside is 0 (not df_scaled = None, which does not make sense).

You can try this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

std_scaler = StandardScaler()
new = train_data[['Fare']]

df_scaled = std_scaler.fit_transform(new)
df_scaled
```

There is a difference between `train_data[['Fare']]` and `train_data['Fare'].values.reshape(1,-1)`.

Let consider `n = len(train_data[['Fare']])`, then:

```
train_data[['Fare']].shape = (n, 1)
train_data['Fare'].values.reshape(1,-1).shape = (1, n)
```

If you apply scaler to shape (1, n), if will fit transform each value separately, instead of the whole list, which will result in value of 0 as nature of standardization.

If you look at the documentation of the function, it requires input to be an ndarray of shape `(n_features,)`. In your case `n_features = 1`, so input should have `shape (1,) which is equivalent to (n,1)`.

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Hope that help.

Comment: thank you very much Quan for this very explanatory answer. It solved my problem!

Comment: You're welcome. You can help tag this as correct answer if it solved your problem then :). Cheers.

Comment: I am new to the platform. I wanted to do it but couldnt find where it is. I cant even vote for it as I dont have 15 reputation to do so.  can you please tell me how I can tag it as the correct answer?

Comment: Ahh never mind. You can do it in the future :). Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

What is df_scaled here? If df_scaled is the Pandas DataFrame object, As we know that pandas DataFrame are 2D objects therefore it is giving an error here.
If you do like this:

```
df_scaled["Fare"] = std_scaler.fit_transform(new)
```

It should run appropriately.